# Using multiple libraries and cannot get my own stylesheet to work. Suggestions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

So I'm creating a website using HTML5. The libraries I'm using are Bootstrap and fullpage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). Whenever I try to apply my own styles from an external stylesheet they are ignored, no matter where the  is in the html document and whether or not I use !important. Inline CSS works, but nothing else. Any suggestions? Should I try purejs-onepage-scroll (https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll) instead of fullpage.js? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are using the <link> to link to your style sheet, also make sure the path to your style sheet is correct, and its referencing the right classes, id's, etc..

Comment: If your css is ignored, it means your browser is not reading it, most likely because your url to the stylesheet is wrong.  Most browsers have a developers tools function that has a network tab that shows which linked files are loaded, their urls and what the status code is.

Comment: What do you exactly want to overwrite ? That'd would help to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stylesheet is loaded last in the header.  Some bootstrap is marked as !important as well, and if yours is marked important and then the browser reads teh bootstrap css, theirs is... more(?) important?  or more recently important.  When using frameworks always include your stylesheet last.  Also, make sure you didn't make a typo when importing your stylesheet into the page.  Make sure the browser isn't reporting a 404 on loading that resource (inspect element, look for a red x on the inspector panel).

Answer (score 0):

On top of what has been mentioned here, check if the style sheet is loaded by your page or not.How should you do it? well, You can use some browser tools to do that , e.g in chrome do right click > inspect element> sources > ctrl+p and type in the name of your external css, if you see code in the css then it is loading ,if you see empty css then you are not linking it correctly, other way to check if there is an issue with the link would be to paste complete path of your css into browser if you see your css then link is fine. If there is no issue with the link then you should check your console for errors.Hope it helps